# Running NUnit tests on Mono on Windows

Tags: c#, windows, unit-testing, mono, nunit

I am new to Mono and I would like to be able to run tests on Mono. I created as simple unit test project in Visual Studio 2012 and compiled it against .NET 4.5.

```
using NUnit.Framework;
namespace ClassLibrary2.Tests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class Class1Tests
    {
        [Test]
        public void MyTest()
        {
            var a = "andsdsaj";
            var b = "fjkfjkdjfk";

            Assert.AreEqual(a, b);
        }
    }
}
```

Then I try to execute it from the Mono Command Prompt:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Mono>nunit-console "C:\Users\boris.m\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ClassLibrary2.Tests\bin\Debug\ClassLibrary2.Tests.dll"
```

I am getting the following error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Mono>nunit-console "C:\Users\boris.m\Documents\Visual Stu
dio 2012\Projects\ClassLibrary2.Tests\bin\Debug\ClassLibrary2.Tests.dll"
NUnit version 2.4.8
Copyright (C) 2002-2007 Charlie Poole.
Copyright (C) 2002-2004 James W. Newkirk, Michael C. Two, Alexei A. Vorontsov.
Copyright (C) 2000-2002 Philip Craig.
All Rights Reserved.

Runtime Environment -
   OS Version: Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7601.65536 Service Pack 1
  CLR Version: 2.0.50727.1433 ( 3.12.0 (Visual Studio built mono) )


Unhandled Exception:
System.ArgumentException: path
  at System.IO.FileSystemInfo.CheckPath (System.String path) [0x00000] in <filen
ame unknown>:0
  at System.IO.DirectoryInfo..ctor (System.String path, Boolean simpleOriginalPa
th) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.IO.DirectoryInfo..ctor (System.String path) [0x00000] in <filename u
nknown>:0
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.DirectoryInfo:.ctor (string)

  at NUnit.Util.AddinManager.RegisterAddins () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0

  at NUnit.Util.AddinManager.InitializeService () [0x00000] in <filename unknown
>:0
  at NUnit.Util.ServiceManager.InitializeServices () [0x00000] in <filename unkn
own>:0
  at NUnit.ConsoleRunner.Runner.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filena
me unknown>:0
  at NUnit.ConsoleRunner.Class1.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filena
me unknown>:0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the Uri class has changed in Mono 3.12 so NUnit 2.4.8 is not returning the correct path to the NUnit assembly. Mono 3.3 on Windows works without any errors.

I have opened a bug on [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=27683) for this problem.

It seems to be possible to use [NUnit 2.6.4](http://github.com/nunit/nunitv2/releases/download/2.6.4/NUnit-2.6.4.zip) with Mono 3.12 on Windows. Downloading the zip file and then extracting it you can run the tests using a command line similar to:

```
mono --runtime=v4.0 nunit-console.exe c:\path\to\tests\MyTests.dll
```

This seems to run the tests but nunit-console.exe seems to never close so you have use ctrl+C to stop it.

Comment: It seems that the latest version is 3.12.0 Am I wrong? Is there any workaround to run NUnit tests on Mono?

Comment: Yes the latest Mono version on Windows is 3.12.0. It is possible to run the tests using NUnit 2.6.4 on Mono. The tests run but nunit-console seems to hang.

Comment: Thanks, dude! Let's wait for the bug fix

Comment: This bug is fixed in Mono 4.0 on Windows. http://www.mono-project.com/download/#download-win